# Ubuntu 22.04 windows network disappears from files manager

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new machine.
When I boot and logon the Files program shows windows network with the various machines on my local network under the other selection.
After some period of time the machines disappear from under the windows network heading.

Restarting Ubuntu fixes this temporarily.

How do I find out why this is happening?

How do I restart this process?

PS: New to Ubuntu.

Comment: Check dmesg or /var/log/syslog at the time you machines disappear. Could it be some "suspend" mode? At least others have written about this problem, citing a line just before it happens:`Oct  9 04:23:51 server NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1665289431.6707] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Oct  9 04:23:51 server NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1665289431.6709] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into those logfiles now that you told me about them. FWIW I have sleep mode turned off unless the network manager can sleep independent of the desktop state.